# Advanced Label in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I have used this extension to find out the age From Date of birth..

```
extension NSDate {
    var age: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Year, fromDate: self, toDate: NSDate(), options: []).year
    }
}

let myDOB = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 1970,
month: 09, day: 10, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! let
myAge = myDOB.age      // 45


func calculateAge (birthday: NSDate) -> Int {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Year, fromDate: birthday, toDate: NSDate(), options: []).year
}

calculateAge(myDOB)   // 45
```

However , I was wondering if there is some way in which as soon as user enters the first two numbers for the month the "/" gets automatically added.Same should happen as soon as the date is entered.

Hence, the required output will always have the correct format. Hence how can it be achieved using cocoa touch class??

Comment: your question shows code about `NSDate`, but what you're interested in is actually `UITextField` and/or `UILabel` it seems, so what code have you tried to do that?

Comment: You have to monitor the text as each character is typed, and modify the string as appropriate

Comment: Use a `UITextField` connected to a `UITextFieldDelegate` and make use of the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` function. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: